# Json - Flatten Key and Values in pyspark

Tags: json, postgresql, parsing, pyspark

In a table having JSON column value as:
{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}

{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"], "ZZZ":["333","444"]}

Need to flatten it as

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 |
| XXX | 456 |
| YYY | 246 |
| YYY | 135 |
| ZZZ | 333 |
| ZZZ | 444 |

Suggestion please..

select
key ,
value ,
from table, json_each(xref_json::json)

Got this result as, need to achieve the above result

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| XXX | ["123","456"] |
| YYY | ["246","135"] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use lateral joins for that:

```
SELECT x.key, y.elem
FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(mytable.xref_json::jsonb) AS x(key,value)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(x.value) AS y(elem)
WHERE x.key IN ('XXX', 'YYY');
```

Comment: In a hive table having JSON column value as: {"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}

Need to flatten it using PYSPARK as below

Key Value
XXX 123
XXX 456
YYY 246
YYY 135
Suggestion please..

Comment: I don't know Pyspark, sorry. Can't you use an SQL statement?

Comment: Thanks for asking. In above postgres sql query I need to add filter criteria, need to fetch only key XXX and YYY. Assume we have plenty of Keys in json column {"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"], "ZZZ":["333","444"]}

Comment: * only keys XXX and YYY and its value too

Comment: Updated the above table as per my request

Comment: Add a `WHERE` condition. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers